# PowerShell prompt color issue

Tags: powershell, colors, prompt

I tried this: [How to colorize the Powershell prompt?](https://superuser.com/questions/1259900/how-to-colorize-the-powershell-prompt)

```
function prompt  
{  
    $ESC = [char]27
    "$ESC[46mPS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) $ESC[0m"  
}
```

And tried this: [Using ANSI escape codes in Powershell prompt to add color, looses meaning after executing some console processes, like git](https://superuser.com/questions/1264444/using-ansi-escape-codes-in-powershell-prompt-to-add-color-looses-meaning-after)

```
function prompt {
    "" + [char]0x001b + "[35m colorized >" + [char]0x001b + "[0m"
}
```

Both options work, but produce same weired problem. When I print quotes( ' or " ), suddenly, right after prompt - character 'm' appears. It does not influes functionality, but this character persists when copying text, so its very annoying to remove 'm' after each paste. I'm using [ConEmu](https://github.com/Maximus5/ConEmu) terminal, but problem persist in standard Windows PowerShell app too.

Here is the picture: [PowerShell prompt screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKT5t.png).

PowerShell info: PSVersion - 5.1.19041.610, BuildVersion - 10.0.19041.610, CLRVersion - 4.0.30319.42000.

Also tried this: [PowerShell prompt with random color](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_prompts?view=powershell-7), and no weired characters appear here, but this prompt doesn't change color dynamicaly when quoting, like normal prompt do.

```
function prompt {
    $color = Get-Random -Min 1 -Max 16
    Write-Host ("PS " + $(Get-Location) +">") -NoNewLine `
     -ForegroundColor $Color
    return " "
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from your first example, I'd suggest to move the « reset color » ANSI escape sequence before the '>' character. Also i prefer to change text foreground color instead of background.

```
function prompt  
{  
    $ESC = [char]27
    "$ESC[36mPS $($executionContext.SessionState.Path.CurrentLocation)$ESC[0m$('>' * ($nestedPromptLevel + 1)) "  
}
```